# Writing to file using Python

Tags: python, file, writefile

I have a file called output.txt, which I want to write into from a few functions around the code, some of which are recursive.
Problem is, every time I write I need to open the file again and again and then everything I wrote before is deleted.
I am quite sure there is a solution, didn't find it in all questions asked here before..

```
def CutTable(Table, index_to_cut, atts, previousSv, allOfPrevSv):
    print ('here we have:')
    print atts
    print index_to_cut
    print Table[2]
    tableColumn=0
    beenHere = False
    for key in atts:
        with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(key)
```

and from another function:

```
def EntForAttribute(possibles,yesArr):
svs = dict()
for key in possibles:
    svs[key]=(yesArr[key]/possibles[key])
for key in possibles:
        with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(key)
```

All output I have is the last one written in one of the functions..

Comment: open file in append mode. `open("output.txt", "a")`

Comment: pass `f` around or make it global

Comment: When I'm doing something like this that initially requires one write then a lot of appends, I usually do something like this: `with open('file.txt', 'w' if not os.path.isfile('file.txt') else 'a') as f:`

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 How does that function differently from `open('file.txt', 'a')`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the second flag when opening the file:

- `w` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be
  erased)
- `a` opens the file for appending

Your code then should be:

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you enter and exit the `with open...` block, you're reopening the file. As the other answers mention, you're overwriting the file each time. In addition to switching to an append, it's probably a good idea to swap your `with` and `for` loops so you're only opening the file once for each set of writes:

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
    for key in atts:
        f.write(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to open the file in append mode (as answered here: [append to file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)) like this:

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
    ## Write out
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. change the 'w' in the file descriptor to 'a' for append.

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("appended text")
```

this has already been answered in this thread.
[How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)